# \phantom not working with $\varbigcirc$

Tags: phantom

When I do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}

$\varbigcirc$ test \par
\phantom{$\varbigcirc$} test

\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

which is not what I would expect. I would expect that the two "test" are left aligned and that the interline space is not as large.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: You can probably fix this by inserting `\leavevmode` before `\phantom`.

Comment: Just use 
`$\varbigcirc$ test \par
\leavevmode\phantom{$\varbigcirc$} test`

Comment: Cool it works! Feel free to make an answer out of your comment. I'm also curious to know what is the effect of `\leavevmode`!

Comment: @Colas it leaves vertical mode (starts a paragraph) actually `$\phantom{\varbigcirc}$` might be more natural and wouldn't need that.